# Which open-source community software is this?

Tags: community

[image]

This is an example of the forum software: https://community.aseprite.org/

I have seen many communities with identical design, suggesting that they use the same self-hosted software.

Is that an open-source software and, if so, which is it?

Comment: Is there any evidence this is open-source software?

Comment: @PhilipKendall That's what I am not sure of, it could be a commercial software, but it must be popular as many communities use it, I am hoping someone here must be knowing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Exchange is not an "identify this software" platform, doubly so when there is no evidence the software is actually Open Source at all.

Comment: www.aseprite.org starts with a big "Buy Now". No source code is mentioned on it. I think it is very likely a closed, proprietary windows tool.

Comment: I suggest to edit this question "Is aseprite an open source software?" So it would be already on-topic (probably with a negative answer).

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica The question isn't about aseprite, that's just an example, I am asking about the software used by it to run the community, proprietary software can use open-source software for creating community.

Comment: @PhilipKendall There is evidence that it was open-source, many open-source communities use it, apart from that, If I knew the software already, why would I ask it? This is the correct platform in my opinion, people here might know the answer.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Aseprite is open-source though, they sell compiled app.

Comment: @PhilipKendall As the answer suggests, it is open-source, so, this is an on-topic question.

Comment: @AbhishekChaudhary "identify this" question is a controversial topic on Stack Exchange. Some sites allow them (SciFi.SE, Biology.SE), others don't (Anime.SE, Movies.SE). Looks like OpenSource.SE hasn't had a [meta] discussion about this topic, and this question has set the precedence.

Comment: @AndrewT. This was the only place where I could get an answer, Maybe someone on Reddit might have known, but, I expected it to work here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the [Discourse](https://discourse.org/) forum software.